# How to fit long equation into a cell of table and how to use table in general

Tags: tables, formatting, lists

I am using tabular for the first time and found it to be unbelievably difficult to use.

But the primary goal for now is to fit a long equation into the cell of a table

```
\pagebreak
\section{List of Things}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | c | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
    \hline
    Long equation & Cat & Dogs & Hats &  Comment \\ \hline

    $x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} G(x,x') + x \frac{d}{dx} G(x,x') + (k^2 x^2-1) G(x,x') = -\delta(x-x')$ & 11C & 22C & Some Stuff. \\ \hline

    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Some stuff. \\ \hline

    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Some stuff. \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Generates:

[image]

1. Is there some way to make the equation less disjointed?
2. Also for whatever reason the vertical line is not appearing next to comment
3. In addition, this is a terrible use of space, the white space appearing above is the entire page and I am using only half of it.

Can someone suggest a way to extend the tabe from the left end all the way to the right side? I tried to adjust the width of each cell, but that results in overflow of the entire page.

Edit:

Thanks to David the table is looking better, but is there a way to use those spaces on the left?
[image]

Thanks for the comments, problem largely resolved

[image]

Comment: the lines are missing as you only have four cells in those rows, you need an extra `&` before the `\\ ` . For the long equation use `\raggedright` then it will look better but still horrible, do you really want a table layout at all for this?

Comment: Are you sure that a table is the correct layout for this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well I can create this in Excel and it would come out roughly the same, just easier to modify.

Comment: @Lookbehindyou: I rather referred to the horrible layout in general, but that's my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yeah but I need some way to list a bunch of line equations side by side or row by row and to put some description on them. I don't see how else to do this in a compact way. I thought a table with big cells could perhaps work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks that actually fixed multiple problems. Do you know how I can drag the table to use those white spaces on the left?

Comment: For what you want it seems that the table isn't enough wide. Do you have in 3., 4. and 5. column multi line text in cells?

Comment: those "white spaces on the left" look terribly like the left margin, which you really don't want to use.  i can't tell whether the section head is indented (it usually isn't), but if you put `\noindent` just before the `\begin{tabular}`, that would avoid any space caused by that situation.

Comment: 1) using \centering and removing the blank lines helps.  2) You need to add one more & each line.  3) I don't care for the default margins either.  Use the geometry package for a larger text area.

Comment: with the wider column at the left, you could make the formula look nicer (my opinion) by using `multlined` and breaking *before* the `=` sign.  requires `\mathtools`.

Comment: @Lookbehindyou the white space on the left is the page margin, as always you can use `\hspace*{-3cm}\begin{tabular...` if you want to steal that space but odd to specify a document margin and then use it for non-marginal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant of Zarko's solution without `mdwtab`: I simply use `cellspace` to define minimal vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifiers prefixed with the letter `S`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{cellspace,tabularx}%
\renewcommand\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\renewcommand\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\section{List of Things}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{$\displaystyle}S{X}<{$} | c | c | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
    \hline
\text{Long equation} & Cat & Dogs & Hats & Comment \\
    \hline
\begin{multlined}[0.9\hsize]
x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} G(x,x') + x\frac{d}{dx}G(x,x')\\
    + (k^2 x^2-1) G(x,x') = -\delta(x-x')
\end{multlined}
                    & 11C & 22C & Some Stuff. & \\
    \hline
\text{Tuesday} & 9C & 19C & Some stuff. & \\
    \hline
\text{Wednesday} & 10C & 21C & Some stuff. & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By use of `mathtools`, `tabularx` and `mdwtab` I create the following table:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage{mdwtab,tabularx}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{List of Things}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{$\displaystyle}X<{$} | c | c | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
    \hlx{hv}
\text{Long equation}    & Cat   & Dogs  & Hats          &  Comment  \\ 
    \hlx{vhv}
\begin{multlined}[0.9\hsize]
x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} G(x,x') + x\frac{d}{dx}G(x,x')\\ 
    + (k^2 x^2-1) G(x,x') = -\delta(x-x')
\end{multlined}
                    & 11C   & 22C   & Some Stuff.   &           \\ 
    \hlx{vhv}
\text{Tuesday}      & 9C    & 19C   & Some stuff.   &           \\ 
    \hlx{vhv}
\text{Wednesday}    & 10C   & 21C   & Some stuff.   &           \\
    \hlx{vh}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

`mdwtab` is (good old) package, which reimplement standard LaTeX `tabular` and `array` packages. It among others define new horizontal lines `\hly{...}` by which option s you can define minimal vertical gaps (option `v`) between cell content and horizontal line (option `h`). Package (unfortunately) is not compatible with `colortbl` and is not maintained anymore.

Instead of it you can use `booktabs` and rules which it define (`toprule,`midrule`and`bottomrule`), however in this case the use of vertical lines is discouraged:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{List of Things}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{$\displaystyle}X<{$} c  c p{2cm} p{2cm}}
    \toprule
\text{Long equation}    & Cat   & Dogs  & Hats          &  Comment  \\ 
    \midrule
\begin{multlined}[0.9\hsize]
x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} G(x,x') + x\frac{d}{dx}G(x,x')\\ 
    + (k^2 x^2-1) G(x,x') = -\delta(x-x')
\end{multlined}
                    & 11C   & 22C   & Some Stuff.   &           \\ 
    \midrule
\text{Tuesday}      & 9C    & 19C   & Some stuff.   &           \\ 
    \midrule
\text{Wednesday}    & 10C   & 21C   & Some stuff.   &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

`\multlined` is defined in package `mathtools`. By option `[0.9\hsize]` you can determine the equation width. Option`showframe` at package geometry shows page layout. Its only helps to see, haw the  table is placed in text. In real use this option had to be erased.

Comment: What are the \hlx and hv, vhv?

Comment: Improved `\hline`. They are defined in package `mdwtab`. I will add some explanation to my answer.

Comment: I would be *very* careful in recommending `mdwtab`.

Comment: @egreg, see edit of my answer. `mdwtab` is not maintaned for decade and half, is not compatible vith `colortbl`, but is stable in considering this limitation work very well. I use it for years.